# Что это может быть?

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Сделал одностраничный сайт и загрузил его на бесплатный хостинг потренироваться. Но не загружаются картинки сайта, частично некоторые... что я сделал не так? Правда параметры изображений (align="right" width="365" height="372" alt="Box") прописал в коде HTML а не CSS, это может повлиять?

Comment: Откройте консоль и посмотрите нет ли легендарных **not found** ответов на запрос картинок

Comment: какую консоль? В браузере нет, а так логотип картинка до половины грузится...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если грузятся до половины - значит вы их так залили, просто перезалейте те картинки которые грузятся не до конца...

В любом случае чтобы в этом убедится не плохо было бы увидеть ссылочку на выше детище :)

Comment: да, точно, уже исправил, никогда бы не догадался) спасибо)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте пути к картинкам. Откройте исходный код прямо из браузера и скопируйте от туда путь к картинке. Затем вставьте в браузер (в адресную строку) и нажмите ENTER. Если путь верный - картинка откроется прямо в браузере.